# Keras Neural Network applied several times with own loss function

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, neural-network, keras

I am new to machine learning tools and have installed Keras in R. While considering simpler models, I want to use neural network now for more special purposes. Generally, the neural network should be a function `Phi: R^d -> R`, where the input is d-dimensional.

Given are d-dimensional data for n time points such that the neural network calculates for each time an 1-dimensional target value. Thereof, I have M samples, i.e. the input is somewhat `(samples,times,input_dimension)=(M,n,d)`, on which the neural network is separately applied. The output should be of the form `(samples,times)=(M,n)`, so that for each time, the predicted value of the neural network is compared with the desired target - and this for every sample. Just for information, the range of the numbers are around `d=5, n=1000, M=100`.

Based on this, one would suggest to run a "usual" neural network on `M*n` samples with d-dimensional input and 1-dimensional target. However, the problem is that the loss function depends on the previous evaluations of the neural networks in each time step, i.e. the loss is of the form

> `l(y_pred,y_target) = sum_{i=1}^n (y^i_pred-y^i_target+f_i(...))^2`

where `y^i_pred` and `y^i_target` are the predicted and target values of the ith time step, respectively, and `f_i` is an additional function (that depends on the second derivative of the neural network, but that is another story, and on the previous losses).

So far I have the following code in order to illustrate my problem:

```
input <- array(data1,dim=c(M,n,d))
target <- array(data2,dim=c(M,n))
myloss <- function(f,y_true,y_pred) {
  K <- backend()
  return(K$sum((y_pred-y_true+f)^2))
}

library(keras)
NN <- keras_model_sequential()
NN %>%
  layer_dense(units=20,activation='relu',input_shape=c(n,d)) %>% 
  layer_dense(units=20,activation='relu') %>%
  layer_dense(units=1,activation='relu')
summary(NN)

NN %>% compile(
  loss function(y_true,y_pred) myloss(f,y_true,y_pred),
  optimizer = "adam",
  metrics = "acc"
)
history <- NN %>% fit(
  input, target, 
  epochs = 30, batch_size = 20, 
  validation_split = 0.1
)
```

I get various error messages (concerning dimension of target and custom loss function), therefore my question: Is it even possible to incorporate my problem into a Keras model? Or should I use convolutional neural networks? I looked also at recurrent networks, but in my case, only the loss is dependent on the "previous values". Perhaps somebody can give an advice, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I have made some progress in understanding the problem. The target should be of the form `target <- array(data2,dim=c(M,n,1))`, then the Keras model enters the training phase, when some usual loss function (e.g. mse) is chosen. Hence, I have still the problem of computing the second derivative, i.e. `k_gradients` of `k_gradients(y_pred,x)` where `x` is passed to the loss function by compiling and defined as `NN$input`, can somebody help at this point?